# VS2010 does not find references to Crystal Reports10?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, reference

Why there is NO references of Crystal Reports 10 when I try to add them to my windows form application project in visual studio 2010?

I have installed Crystal Reports 10 recently (after installed VS2010) and tried to add some references such as 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, ...' to my project but actually, there is no references in 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.5\bin'

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560630/vs-2010-net-4-cannot-found-crystalreports-references

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/24bd3f52-8b22-47ee-90eb-2504d49a4625